# How Do I Solve "Trufle Init 'command not found'" Terminal Issue on Mac?

Tags: macos, blockchain, solidity

I'm trying to set up the tools needed to develop a decentralised application.

I would need to input `truffle init` to my terminal as part of the process. I've tried multiple times to solve the "command not found" message I keep getting when I input `truffle init`, but I have not found a solution. I'm not sure if there are any other ways I could bypass this issue. It seems as though a lot of the developer tools I've tried to install for blockchain development have been difficult to install or integrate with my Mac.

Thank you for any assistance provided.

Comment: And how and where did you install truffle? It’s obviously not part of macOS, but something you have to install. Are you asking us how to find a file in macOS or are you asking how to install truffle? (As an aside, either way, this isn’t a programming question appropriate for Stack Overflow.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install truffle globally?

```
sudo npm install -g truffle@latest
```

Please verify that you have installed truffle properly using

```
truffle -version
```